# launch javafx app in terminal in Intellij idea

Tags: ubuntu, javafx

I want my app launch from app.desktop in Ubuntu.
Before I created app.sh and want write script

```
#!/bin/bash
APP_NAME=my-app
BIN_PATH=out/production/$APP_NAME/
RES_PATH=res/
java -cp $BIN_PATH:lib/*.jar org.kl.ui.Starter
```

In app I use jfoenix library.
But when I want run bash script I got error

---

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/igor/.starter/threshold/out/production/threshold/view/MainView.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2863)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2676)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at org.kl.ui.Starter.initController(Starter.java:63)
    at org.kl.ui.Starter.start(Starter.java:40)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXDatePicker
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2931)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2920)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2861)
    ... 16 more
Exception running application org.kl.ui.Starter
```

Comment: Did you make sure the correct version of JFoenix (`9.*`) is added to the classpath at runtime?

Comment: Yes I have 9.0.1 version. When I run in Intellij Idea all ok! But I want make desktop runner app.